# send message to specified Red5 client

Tags: red5

When I was make a voice chat, I found a problem.

the problem is how to send message to specified RED5 client (Shared Object).

this is what I want :

**Client 1**

```
Message from client 2 : Hello!
To client 2 : How are you ?
etc....
```

**Client2**

```
To client 1 : Hello!
Message from client 12 : 
etc....
```

**Client3**

```
Message from client X : How are you ?
etc....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sharedObject to send a message to another clients with your own clientID and to clientID you want( something like this: sharedobject.send(fromId,toID,message)) , and other clients receive this message and decide to display it or not.

hope can help you.